# Загрузка скрипта через require.js

Tags: javascript

Привет.Разобрался как подключать поочередно набор скриптов с вызовом callback-функции по окончанию их загрузки.

```
require(["file1","file2"], function() {
            console.log('Hello')    ;
        });
```

Хочу разобратся теперь с функцией define();

```
define("file2",['file1'],function(){console.log('World')})
```

Мне нужно загрузить файл file2 , перед которым должен быть загружен  file1.После загрузки всех скриптов должен вызваться коллбек.Он не срабатывает
Поправте пожалуйста меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя модуля работает только тогда когда мы билд делаем. Иначе будет ошибка.
Что бы перед файлом2 загрузить файл1, лучше это прописать в конфиге в зависимостях

```
shim : {
  'file2' : {deps : ['file1']}
}
```

И просто в модуле загрузить файл2, и все зависимости подтянутся.

Comment: Получилось.Спасибо.А можно сделать проверку: если файл не загрузился - сделать повторную загрузку??

Answer (score 1):

*Метод define служит для описания модулей и имеет следующий синтаксис:*

```
define( [moduleName,] dependencies, callback)
moduleName - имя модуля (необязательный параметр)
dependencies - массив зависимостей(с другими модулями)
callback - тело модуля, в которое передаются dependencies
```

Т.е. в Вашем случае

```
define( "unit", /* необязательно */
    ['file2', 'file1'],
    function( file2, file1 ){
     console.log('World');
    }
);
```

[Тут можно почитать подробнее](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/10/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-requirejs/)

Comment: Спасибо Вам.